# Javascript: Subtract time with another fixed time

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

Consider I have following date and time in 24 hours format.
**Example**

```
2015/04/02 12:00
2015/03/02 14:00
```

I have to subtract the above time with `9 hours` so that I will get

```
2015/04/02 -> 3 (hours)
2015/03/02 -> 5 (hours)
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="formName" onsubmit="return checkDate(this)">
        <input type="text"  value="" name="date1" />
        <input type="text" value="" name="date2"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkDate(theForm)
{
    var a = theForm.date1.value;
    var b = theForm.date2.value;

    var date1 = new Date(a);
    var date2 = new Date(b);

    var dateStart = new Date();
    var dateEnd = new Date();

    dateStart.setHours(9);

    Start_sec =  (date1/ 1000.0) - (dateStart/ 1000.0);
    Start_hours = parseInt(Start_sec / 60 / 60);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  Start_hours ;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: My question is how to subtract the time with other fixed time. Example the time is 18:00, so I have to subtract **9 hours(fixed)** and it will become **9 hours**..18-9 = 9

Comment: `var t = new Date(2015,2,3,18); a.setTime(a-9*60*60*1000)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
function checkDate(theForm)
{
    var a = theForm.date1.value;
    var b = theForm.date2.value;

    var date1 = new Date(a);
    var date2 = new Date(b);

    date1.setHours(date1.getHours() - 9);
    date2.setHours(date2.getHours() - 9);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "Date 1 : " + date1.toString() + "<br/>Date 2 : " + date2.toString();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how could I compare date1.toString() >= 4.5?

Comment: @Sollo why do u want to compare? you only wants to substract 9 hous from each of the date right?

Comment: I want to check whether the answer(hours) is bigger or smaller than 4.5

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable to use third party libraries, then you can achieve this task simply using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). In one line, you can accomplish the task with this code:

```
moment('2015/04/02 12:00').subtract('hours',9).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm')

//just a number plus the word 'hours'
.format('h [hours]')

//time only
.format('h:mm')
```

Occasionally I update this fiddle I maintain with more examples: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesWClark/9PAFg/

Comment: External js not require in such easy problm.

Answer (score 0):

You can just literally subtract 9 hours directly...:

```
var t = new Date(2015,2,3,18);
t.setTime(t - 9*60*60*1000);          //subtract 9 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date("2015/04/02 12:00");
var out = new Date(date.getTime() - 32400000); //9*60*60*1000
```